# Chess Game Project VB.net

Tags: vb.net, input, logic, chess

I am making a chess game in vb 2010 here's my codes UPDATED

```
Imports System.Drawing.Image
Public Class Form1
Dim MD As Boolean
Dim BLACK(5) As Image
Dim WHITE(5) As Image
Dim corX1st As String
Dim corY1st As String
Dim corX2nd As String
Dim corY2nd As String

Dim PIC As Image
Dim box As PictureBox

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BLACK(0) = My.Resources.PB
    BLACK(1) = My.Resources.RB
    BLACK(2) = My.Resources.HB
    BLACK(3) = My.Resources.BB
    BLACK(4) = My.Resources.QB
    BLACK(5) = My.Resources.KB

    WHITE(0) = My.Resources.PW
    WHITE(1) = My.Resources.RW
    WHITE(2) = My.Resources.HW
    WHITE(3) = My.Resources.BW
    WHITE(4) = My.Resources.QW
    WHITE(5) = My.Resources.KW

    a1.Image = BLACK(1)
    b1.Image = BLACK(2)
    c1.Image = BLACK(3)
    d1.Image = BLACK(4)
    e1.Image = BLACK(5)
    f1.Image = BLACK(3)
    g1.Image = BLACK(2)
    h1.Image = BLACK(1)
    a2.Image = BLACK(0)
    b2.Image = BLACK(0)
    c2.Image = BLACK(0)
    d2.Image = BLACK(0)
    e2.Image = BLACK(0)
    f2.Image = BLACK(0)
    g2.Image = BLACK(0)
    h2.Image = BLACK(0)

    a8.Image = WHITE(1)
    b8.Image = WHITE(2)
    c8.Image = WHITE(3)
    d8.Image = WHITE(4)
    e8.Image = WHITE(5)
    f8.Image = WHITE(3)
    g8.Image = WHITE(2)
    h8.Image = WHITE(1)
    a7.Image = WHITE(0)
    b7.Image = WHITE(0)
    c7.Image = WHITE(0)
    d7.Image = WHITE(0)
    e7.Image = WHITE(0)
    f7.Image = WHITE(0)
    g7.Image = WHITE(0)
    h7.Image = WHITE(0)

    For Each a As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf a Is PictureBox Then
            AddHandler a.MouseDown, AddressOf PictureBox_MouseDown
            AddHandler a.MouseMove, AddressOf PictureBox_MouseMove
            AddHandler a.DragEnter, AddressOf PictureBox_DragEnter
            AddHandler a.DragDrop, AddressOf PictureBox_DragDrop
            a.AllowDrop = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub PictureBox_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    Dim a As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    PIC = a.Image
    box = a
    corX1st = a.Location.X.ToString
    corY1st = a.Location.Y.ToString
    txt1.Text = corX1st
    txt2.Text = corY1st
    If Not a.Image Is Nothing Then
        MD = True
        TextBox1.Text = MD
        If a.Image Is BLACK(0) Then
        End If
    Else
        MD = False
        TextBox1.Text = MD
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub PictureBox_MouseMove(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If MD = True Then
        box.DoDragDrop(PIC, DragDropEffects.Move)
        'MsgBox("tae0")
    End If
    MD = False

End Sub
Private Sub PictureBox_DragEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
    Else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub PictureBox_DragDrop(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
    If Not e.KeyState = 8 Then
        Dim a As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
        corX2nd = a.Location.X.ToString
        corY2nd = a.Location.Y.ToString
        txt1.Text = corX2nd
        txt2.Text = corY2nd

        If Not a Is box Then
            If PIC Is BLACK(0) Then
                MsgBox("pawnblack")
                If corY1st - corY2nd = 76 And corX1st = corX2nd Then
                    If a.Image Is Nothing Then
                        a.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
                        box.Image = Nothing
                    Else
                        MsgBox("There is a piece there")
                    End If
                ElseIf corY1st - corY2nd = 76 And corX1st - corX2nd = 76 Or corY1st - corY2nd = 76 And corX2nd - corX1st = 76 Then
                    a.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
                    box.Image = Nothing

                    MsgBox("good")
                End If

            ElseIf PIC Is BLACK(1) Then
                a.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
                box.Image = Nothing
            ElseIf PIC Is BLACK(2) Then
            ElseIf PIC Is BLACK(3) Then
            ElseIf PIC Is BLACK(4) Then
            ElseIf PIC Is BLACK(5) Then
            End If

        Else
            MsgBox(" DO nothing")
        End If
        End If
End Sub
```

End Class

UPDATE....

GOT THE PAWN LOGIC 
my problem is that of a KNIGHT or ROOT logic
i can move my rook forward backward left right but what if there is a chess piece blocking the way of a rook. it still goes to the picture box jumping over the chess piece here's my code

```
ElseIf PIC Is BLACK(1) Then
                If corX1st < corX2nd And corY1st = corY2nd Then
                    For ew As Integer = corX1st To 597
                        If corX1st <= corX2nd And corY1st = corY1st Then
                            a.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
                            box.Image = Nothing
                            corX1st += 76
                            MsgBox("wee" + corX1st)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                ElseIf corX2nd <= corX1st And corY1st = corY2nd Then
                    For aw As Integer = 65 To corX1st
                        If corX1st >= corX2nd And corY1st = corY1st Then
                            a.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
                            box.Image = Nothing
                            corX1st -= 76
                            MsgBox("waa" + corX1st)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                ElseIf corY1st <= corY2nd And corX1st = corX2nd Then
                    For ow As Integer = corY1st To 544
                        If corY1st <= corY2nd And corX1st = corX2nd Then
                            a.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
                            box.Image = Nothing
                            corY1st += 76
                            MsgBox("woo" + corY1st)
                            Exit For
                        Else
                        End If
                    Next
                ElseIf corY1st >= corY2nd And corX1st = corX2nd Then
                    For iw As Integer = 12 To corY1st
                        If corY1st >= corY2nd And corX1st = corX2nd Then
                            a.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
                            box.Image = Nothing
                            corY1st -= 76
                            MsgBox("wii" + corY1st)
                            Exit For
                        Else
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
```

it would be better if i can post a screeny but need 1500 rep just imaging PICTUREBOXES as chessboard evenly spaced and size 70,70... thats is why i plus and minus 76 to corY1st and corX1st to get to the 2nd coordinates...

CHESS PIECE BLOCKING is a pain... will update later

Comment: you probably need **several** classes

Comment: i will but for now i put it on DragDrop Event

Comment: You should have a function that takes a current piece and returns all the available moves. That way you only need to look at this list.

Comment: how to detect if theres a PIECE BLOCKING MY WAY

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the OnClick event for an image and then write code to highlight it.  Once you know which piece is selected then handle the Onclick for where you want to put the selected piece.  The actual logic for the chess game should be inside its own class though.

Comment: putted the CHESS PIECE LOGIC in DragDrop